# How should I be using class variables in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class-variables

This has been bugging me for a long time, and I have tried to look it up many times.

When I first began learning Objective-C, I remember looking into class variables. I saw many threads on stack overflow and elsewhere that basically said, "Objective-C doesn't support class variables like C does, but there are some workarounds."

Reading this made me shy away from using class variables, especially because I have read hundreds of times that global variables tarnish the elegance of OOP.

So I have a very open ended, opinionated, and conversational question:
**Should I use class variables in objective C? Also, am I doing it right?**

Here is my situation: I am making an app, and I set up a touch handling class to deal with all the input received from screen touches. The data is pretty useful, and I would like every single sprite to have access to it.

Since every object is a subclass of my GameObject class, I figure I just make a class variable, done like so:

header for GameObject class:

```
+(SSTouchHandler *)touchHandler;
+(void)setHandler:(SSTouchHandler *)handler;
```

implementation for GameObject class:

```
static SSTouchHandler *touchHandler = nil;

+(SSTouchHandler *)touchHandler
{
    if (touchHandler)
        return touchHandler;
    else
        return nil;
}

+(void)setHandler:(SSTouchHandler *)handler
{
    touchHandler = handler;
}
```

Now, this works. This works beautifully.

I can refer to my handler with [GameObject touchHandler] from every place I need.

This is all I could ever want and more.

But should I use this method? Am I dirtying the beauty that is object oriented programming?

Is there a way I should touch up this process to make it work optimally?

Thanks for any and all input, I probably rambled a bit, I just don't want to proceed with a faulty game structure.

Comment: Just as in other languages, static variables have their uses in Objective-C.  But it's very easy to abuse them, just as in other languages.  Generally, when you hit the "sweet spot" for designing an app the need for statics drops to a pretty low level.

Comment: That's what I figured, makes sense. This is my first app (At least, the first one I plan on finishing and releasing) and I honestly only see the need for ONE static variable. Do you think I can go for it?

Comment: The `if` block in your `touchHandler` method is not needed, just do `return touchHandler;`. If it's nil, it will return nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I saw many threads on stack overflow and elsewhere that basically
>   said, "Objective-C doesn't support class variables like C does, but
>   there are some workarounds.

"Class variables" make no sense in the context of C since C is not object oriented.

> So I have a very open ended, opinionated, and conversational question:
>   Should I use class variables in objective C? Also, am I doing it
>   right?

This is more of a general OOP question than anything specific to Objective-C. The answer tends to be pretty subjective, but in general I'd say to avoid them unless you're trying to set a property of some sort that affects **all instances** of a class.

> Here is my situation: I am making an app, and I set up a touch
>   handling class to deal with all the input received from screen
>   touches. The data is pretty useful, and I would like every single
>   sprite to have access to it.

It sounds to me like a better design pattern for this would be to pass the `SSTouchHandler` instance as a parameter to the initializer of the sprite objects that use it. e.g.:

```
@interface GameObject : NSObject
- (id)initWithTouchHandler:(SSTouchHandler *)handler;
@end
```

Now, if you really want to use the same instance of `SSTouchHandler` for every `GameObject`, you have two options:

1) The controller/factory that creates the `GameObject` objects should create and keep a reference to a single instance of `SSTouchHandler`, and then initialize any new `GameObject` instances with it. For example:

```
@interface GameObjectController : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) SSTouchHandler *touchHandler;
- (GameObject *)newGameObject;
@end

@implementation

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _touchHandler = [[SSTouchHandler alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (GameObject *)newGameObject
{
    return [[GameObject alloc] initWithTouchHandler:self.touchHandler];
}

@end
```

2) You could make `SSTouchHandler` a [shared singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and call methods on the shared instance directly from the implementation of `GameObject`. However, shared singletons are discouraged in OOP because they hide dependencies and make it difficult to unit test code that depends on them. You shouldn't go down this route unless you deem it absolutely necessary.

> implementation for GameObject class: ...

If you decide that the patterns above aren't suitable for your use case (and that sometimes does happen), yes that is essentially how you would implement class properties in Objective-C. One thing:

```
if (touchHandler)
        return touchHandler;
    else
        return nil;
```

This is not necessary, you can just `return touchHandler` since it will be `nil` anyways if not set.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very in detail answer. I am pretty sure I will need an TouchHandler for every instance, and my previous solution was to toss the same pointer to the initial TouchHandler around (using initialization). The shared singleton looks like exactly what I need, going to research it. Also, the first solution is what I went with earlier (from what it looks like) and the issue was that I ended up with GameObjects being made in many places. So I had trouble initializing them all properly.

Comment: Read the bit about shared singletons being a last resort, so I think I'm going to stick with the class variable method. It works and I understand it, and as far as I can tell, it works pretty lag-free. Your answer was very helpful though, and I also am seeing if solution #1 has a potential.

Comment: For this particular situation (based on my understanding given the limited context) it seems like you have to use the class variable approach or introduce a singleton _somewhere_ down the line, if you need to create these GameObject's throughout your code. You could either make `GameObjectController` a singleton so your other code can call it to create new `GameObject` instances that are initialized with the shared touch handler, or make the `SSTouchHandler` itself a singleton. In my opinion a shared singleton `GameObjectController` / `GameObjectFactory` would be the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If it works, you're done.  I think there are some improvements, though.  First, you might like to use an instance var here: it's not more complicated, but it allows some flexibility in the future (e.g. if you want to make two views side by side).  Also, using a bare pointer is not so good; the class here does not own the pointer, and it can be left dangling!  Defining the touchHandler as a property (also an instance var) takes care of that problem.

Comment: This is where you might be able to help. Previously, I have been using an instance variable to handle this functionality. I just initialize all my objects using the pointer. I even set it up so that every time I add the child to my scene (did I mention I am using spritekit?) it sets my touchhandler to the object.

The issue that comes from that is that I need to constantly find ways to set that variable up, depending on how my gameobjects are initialized and from where. Should I just make all my gameobjects take a touchhandler during initialization?